# PVZ1 GOTY does not start (Compatibility Issues)

Tags: technical-issues, plants-vs-zombies

I've been trying to play **PVZ1**'s GOTY (Game of the Year) version, but I'm currently unable to do so. After opening the .exe file, the game opens, fullscreens for a few seconds and then doesn't display, leaving only the desktop. However, the game is still shown running on the task bar, even though it seems to pause when it's minimized. When I try to click on the program icon on the task bar, it does the same: runs for a few seconds, then minimizes.

I'm using Windows 10, and the same copy of the game had worked on another machine running Windows 10. I've tried using the compatibility setting, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Is this the Steam version? What are your machine specifications?